# Change values in an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, podio

I have a field in our CRM system with order numbers listed in the following way:

```
544,543,53
```

*Note : This is an example, the amount and size of these numbers can vary.*

How do I change these numbers to:

```
HPO0000000544,HPO0000000543,HPO0000000044
```

Please note that the amount of 0s in the HPO codes depends on the size of the order number. HPO should always be followed by 10 numbers (0s + the order number).

I've tried to look for the solution, but haven't been able to find anything. Unfortunately I don't know enough about javascript to write the code myself.

Comment: `I've tried to look for the solution`.....where is the tried code?

Comment: `'HPO' + ('' + 544).padStart(10, '0')` see [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: try out something and post the code here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to map the array (map each value of the array to another one) by using [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```js
function toHPO(number) {
    return `HPO${number.toString().padStart(10, '0')}`;
}
const arr = [544,543,53];
console.log(arr.map(toHPO));
```

Note that you might need to add a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Polyfill) depending on [which browsers you target](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pad-start-end).

Answer (score 0):

Podio calculation fields work with ECMAscript 5, padStart() was introduced with ES 2017,  so you can't use it.

```
var
arr = [544,543,53],
pad = "000000000"; // 9 zeros
arr.map(function (item){return "HPO" + (pad + item).substr(-10)}).join()
// HPO0000000544,HPO0000000543,HPO0000000053
```